# Reset password Email not sent ?? Email sender works for email confirmation but not for password reset

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asp.net-core, forgot-password

Hi guys i'm trying to configure a password reset email sender but when I run the web app (i'm using .net core 2.1) it doesn't give any error it just redirect to page(as it should) but no email is sent.The email sender is actually working (it sends a email with a verification code). Please check the code below and help me find the error i have no clue.

> ForgetPassword.cshtml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using ProjectiWebFinal.Areas.Identity.Services;
using ProjectiWebFinal.Data;

namespace ProjectiWebFinal.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class ForgotPasswordModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public ForgotPasswordModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string UserName { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.UserName);
                if (user == null || !(await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
                {
                    // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                    return RedirectToPage("./ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
                }

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please 
                // visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
                var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ResetPassword",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
                    user.Email,
                    "Reset Password For"+user.UserName,
                    $"Please reset your password by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>." +
                    $"You will be redirected to another page to Create your new password!");

                return RedirectToPage("./ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

> ForgotPassword.cshtml

```
@page
@model ForgotPasswordModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Forgot your password?";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<h4>Enter your email.</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.UserName"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

> ResetPassword.cshtml

```
@page
@model ResetPasswordModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Reset password";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<h4>Reset your password.</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input asp-for="Input.Code" type="hidden" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Username"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Username" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Username" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

> ResetPassword.cshtml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using ProjectiWebFinal.Data;

namespace ProjectiWebFinal.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class ResetPasswordModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public ResetPasswordModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            public string Username { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

            public string Code { get; set; }
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet(string code = null)
        {
            if (code == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("A code must be supplied for password reset.");
            }
            else
            {
                Input = new InputModel
                {
                    Code = code
                };
                return Page();
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
                return RedirectToPage("./ResetPasswordConfirmation");
            }

            var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, Input.Code, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./ResetPasswordConfirmation");
            }

            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

> Here it is Myemailsender.cs that i use for emali confirmation and it's working(it sends the email to the user.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjectiWebFinal.Areas.Identity.Services
{
    public class MyEmailSender : IEmailSender
    {
        private string host;
        private int port;
        private bool enableSSL;
        private string Email;
        private string password;

        // Get our parameterized configuration
        public MyEmailSender(string host, int port, bool enableSSL, string email, string password)
        {
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
            this.enableSSL = enableSSL;
            this.Email = email;
            this.password = password;
        }

        // Use our configuration to send the email by using SmtpClient
        public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient(host, port)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Email, password),
                EnableSsl = enableSSL
            };
            return client.SendMailAsync(
                new MailMessage(Email, email, subject, htmlMessage) { IsBodyHtml = true }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger to see where the logic fails?

Comment: here i'll add what you asking for

Comment: Add a breakpoint to `ForgotPasswordModel.OnPostAsync` and run it with a debugger attached. There's a good chance that either `user` is `null` or  `await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)` returns `false`.

Comment: the breaking poit is the red dot that you can add in the far left of the visual studio? and what is should tell me or what kind of error it should appear just to know

Comment: Yeah. Have a read of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019. Using breakpoints, you can see if the function returns before sending an email as I suggested it might be, above.

Comment: Thanks a lot man i spotted a mistake it was giving the user null as i was using FindByEmailAsync and sending username as a parameter this breaking point is an  amaizing tool. Really helped a lot thanks man!